# Static Broadcast Receiver not being called for SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android

i am writing a broadcastreciever to listen for SMS_RECEIVED action .it works perfectly fine if i register it dynamically but if i register it statically in the Manifest file the broadcast receiver is not being called.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiverBroadcast"><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
        </intent-filter></receiver>
```

My broadcast reciever is as follows

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action=intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION))
        {
Log.v("sms", "reciever called");
            Object[] messages=(Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            for(Object message:messages)
            {
                byte[] messagedata=(byte[])message;
                SmsMessage smsmessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu(messagedata);
                processmessage(smsmessage,context);
            }

        }


    }

    private void processmessage(SmsMessage smsmessage,Context c) {
        String from=smsmessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        String messcontent=smsmessage.getMessageBody();
        Toast.makeText(c,"from ="+from+" and mess="+messcontent,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("sms","from ="+from+" and mess="+messcontent);
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tech.myfirst" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".SmsReceiverDemo"
            android:label="SmsReciever Demo"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.tech.myfirst.MyReceiverBroadcast"><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
        </intent-filter></receiver>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

I have added all the necessary permissions.
What i am missing here.
i am running the program on emulator nexus 5 api 21.
thanks

Comment: Where are you declaring the receiver in your manifest ?

Comment: within the application tag

Comment: Have you tried instead of doing `.MyBroadcastReceiver` doing the full package name. I have had that happen to me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct, it appears the problem is that you've misspelled `RECEIVED` in the `<intent-filter>`'s `<action>` for the `<receiver>` entry in the manifest. It should be:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
```

You might also want to check the value of the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` String.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and was solved by changing the attribute

```
android:name=".MyReceiverBroadcast"
```

To

```
android:name="my.package.name.MyReceiverBroadcast"
```

I don't know why this is happening, but it worked for me.